# Tensorflow 1.14+: dockerized task based flask api doesn't run and or stalls?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, flask, redis

I have made, trained and saved a simple `tf.keras` model. I then set up a basic task-based api via flask, redis and rq.

It works essentially like:

- api is called with input
- the task (evaluating the input with the model) is queued
- the task status is checked until complete.

Outside of docker this works quite nicely.

I am using docker-compose to spin up the redis server, worker service and flask api.

The flask and worker service (which evaluate the model) are build from a Dockerfile, starting with either `FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter` or `FROM debian:buster-slim`.

While, in either case, no gpus are detected, the issue stems from the loaded model not wanting to run on the CPU (it does work outside of docker). This is interesting, because part of the task calls several tensorflow operations (such as converting the input to work with `tf.data`). If I comment out only the evaluation of the model, but allow the other `tf` functions to run, everything works as expected.

When I spin up via `docker-compose` some of the logs I see are:

```
worker | 2019-10-20 12:58:48.602164: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
worker | 2019-10-20 12:58:48.633121: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2400000000 Hz
worker | 2019-10-20 12:58:48.636200: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x3a82e10 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
worker | 2019-10-20 12:58:48.636236: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
```

when the task is queue `worker` logs:

```
worker | 2019-10-20 12:59:47.726320: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
```

Looking at other SO questions, I know I can mute this warning if I have a GPU (which even with `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter`, docker does not seem to find).

I have tried adding the specified environment variable, e.g.

```
os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit'
```

but then it complains about ALA, etc.

Interestingly, if called outside the task framework (e.g. `print` the results in the flask `views.py` file), docker logs the results almost instantaneously.

*Update*: Actually it is a bit more weird than that.

Consider:

```py
# views.py
# ...
print('toggle')

print('about to call')
results = evaluate_model(dummy_input) # model.predict(...)
print('called')
print(results)
```

when I call `docker-compose up`
I see

```
[flask] toggle
[flask] about to call
[flask] called
```

Then if I comment out `print('toggle')` I see

```
[flask] toggle #<--- should not see this, it is commented out
[flask] about to call
[flask] called
[flask] [[...], [...], ..., [...]] #<--- matrix
```

If I then uncomment `print('toggle')` I see

```
[flask] about to call # toggle should be printed but it isnt.
[flask] called
[flask] [[...], [...], ..., [...]] #<--- matrix
```

It is as if the process running is lost and then found a moment later?
Note, this doesn't affect other endpoints of the api i.e. when flask is loaded it is not stuck waiting for the model to return.

A MWE of the docker setup can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-nuxt-flask-redis-rq) (does not include TF, just how flask, redis, rq, and frontend are wired)

Any ideas?

## Update

[MWE](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-tf-nuxt-flask-redis-rq) of set up.

If you clone this repo and run

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.ai.development.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.ai.development.yml up
```

you can see the super simple [notebook](https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-tf-nuxt-flask-redis-rq/blob/master/notebooks/Make%20Toy%20Model.ipynb) that produces a toy tf.keras model (straight from TF documentation).

This model is saved and then loaded, in the notebook to ensure that the issue is not the export / import of the model.

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.development.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.web.development.yml up
```

launches the frontend (nuxt + ngx) and the backend (flask + rq + redis).

Of interest is the file `/backend/app/api/utils.py`, which has the very simple task of:

```
import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np, os

model_file = os.path.join('/app/models/', 'model.h5')
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_file)

def predict_model():
    dummy_input = np.zeros((28, 28)).reshape((-1, 28, 28))
    predicted   = model.predict(dummy_input) # line 2 of predict_model function
    predicted = None
    return {
        'results': predicted
    }
```

going to `localhost:9061/model-task` submits a task (`predict_model`). 
commenting out line two works fine, keeping it in has the queue start the task and never finish.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, the it might be an issue with multi-threading. Try setting `threads = 1` in your ini file, if you want you may always scale up with increasing a number of `processes`, but not `threads`.

Comment: From the MWE repo (used to build the application discussed in this question), where would input the ini file and how would I get docker to use it?

Comment: you can also set it in flask as a parameter to `run()` method., e.g. `app.run(threaded=False, processes=3)`. I suspect it is somewhere here https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-nuxt-flask-redis-rq/blob/master/backend/manage.py

Comment: Another way is to modify `deploy.sh` and add ` --threads=1` to gunicorn https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-nuxt-flask-redis-rq/blob/master/backend/deploy.sh

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestions. `threaded=False, processes=3` doesn't seem to work, neither does adding `--threads=1` to `gunicorn`.

Comment: If this helps, the function `evaluate_model(...)`, has some `tf` functions, then `model.predict`, some post processing, then returns. If I comment out `model.predict`, things work as expected.

Comment: it seems that `W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.` may be related?

Comment: added a MWE with TF here https://gitlab.com/SumNeuron/docker-tf-nuxt-flask-redis-rq . Should look very familiar (as stated in the question it was built off the other MWE).

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong. When you start flask app you should then import tensorflow and load the model, then just call predict. Otherwise I think your REST API call might be just timing-out.

Comment: yes and now. The rest of the app doesn't need TF, just the worker in the task. Moving the imports outside of the worker doesn't seem to cause any harm. The offeneder (the difference between it running and not running) is whether or not I try to load my model outside of the task function or not. Previously I was doing that (trying to do persistent memory of the model), now I load the model when the task is called. The latter works, but has the drawback of init setup time